# webscraping error, it says out of index, whats up

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

```
I'm trying to make an app that scrapes my top ten favorite space related stock prices. but
```

List item I have some trouble with my code and I'm new to scraping. Once I get this to work, I want to put it into a csv file and make a bar graph with it, I would love some help and suggestions. Also Im doing this in Anaconda :

```
#import libraries 
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#grequests is a unique library that allows you to use many urls with ease
#must install qrequest in annacode use : conda install -c conda-forge grequests
#if you know a better way to do this, please let me know
import grequests

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick compaines with pure play interest in space

urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)

results = grequests.map(unsent_request)

def  parsePrice(r):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
        price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
        return price

for r in results:
   parsePrice(r)
```

SO what code is bringing this error:

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9ac8cb94b6fb> in <module>
      5 
      6 for r in results:
----> 7    parsePrice(r)

<ipython-input-6-9ac8cb94b6fb> in parsePrice(r)
      1 def  parsePrice(r):
      2         soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
----> 3         price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
      4         return price
      5 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

whats up?

Comment: the issue is `soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})` returns an empty list, so when you try to call item in index 0 with `[0]`, there is no index 0, hence `list index out of range`

Comment: what value are you actual after? There's an easier way to use this without beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

The data on the page is with in `<table>` tags. Use pandas' `.read_html()`, as it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood. That way you can grab more.

That data is also available through API/XHR, but won't get into that, as that'll be slightly more complex.

```
import pandas as pd

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick compaines with pure play interest in space
urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  

def  parsePrice(r):
    df = pd.read_html(r)[0].T
    cols = list(df.iloc[0,:])
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([list(df.iloc[1,:])], columns=cols)
    temp_df['url'] = r
    return temp_df

df = pd.DataFrame()
for r in urls:
   df = df.append(parsePrice(r), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('path/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
     52 Week Range            Ask Avg. Volume           Bid      Day's Range    Open Previous Close   Volume                                                url
0      7.32 - 9.87     8.09 x 800       23415    8.06 x 800      8.01 - 8.11    8.10           8.01     6337              https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/
1    32.14 - 42.77   32.74 x 1100       41759  32.59 x 1000    32.28 - 32.75   32.32          32.28    14685  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.t...
2     5.55 - 27.29     6.64 x 800     5746553   6.63 x 2900      6.51 - 6.68    6.64           6.65   995245  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fi...
3    55.93 - 97.31    72.21 x 800      281600  72.16 x 1000    71.51 - 72.80   72.26          72.32    74758  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.t...
4  144.27 - 220.03  215.54 x 1000     1560562  215.37 x 800  214.87 - 217.45  215.85         214.86   203957  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsr...
5  100.48 - 149.81   145.03 x 800     2749725  144.96 x 800  144.41 - 145.56  145.49         144.52   489169          https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1
6  189.35 - 351.53   343.34 x 800      280325  342.80 x 800  342.84 - 346.29  344.16         343.58    42326          https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1
7  3.5800 - 9.7900  4.1400 x 1300      778343  4.1300 x 800  4.1200 - 4.2000  4.1700         4.1500    62335         https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1
8     6.90 - 12.09     7.37 x 900     2280333    7.38 x 800      7.24 - 7.48    7.30           7.22   539082  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.t...
9  292.47 - 446.01   348.73 x 800     4420225  348.79 x 800  345.70 - 350.42  350.22         348.84  1258813  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=...
```

But IF you must go the route of BeautifulSoup, your `find_all()` is incorrect. First the class is strictly the text between the double quotes after `class=`. You've included other attributes of the element such as `datareact-id`, and the actual content/text that you are wanting to pull. Secondly, that class is a child of the `<span>` tag, not the `div` tag. If you pull the `div` tag, that's fine, but then you'd still need to go inside THAT element to get the text.

Give this a try:

```
import bs4
import requests

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick compaines with pure play interest in space
urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  

def  parsePrice(r):
        resp = requests.get(r)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html")
        price=soup.find_all('span',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'})[0].text
        return price

for r in urls:
   print (parsePrice(r))
```

**Output:**

```
8.06
32.76
6.60
72.22
215.54
145.14
343.28
4.1550
7.43
348.32
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer - yours negates it completely :)

Comment: Your solution was technically correct, in that he wouldn't have gotten that error, but fundamentally, he would never get anything, which ultimately would lead to another question of "why do I never get an output?" Which is why I hinted towards addressing the root of the issue

Comment: thanks!!!! SO im curious for the first section of code you wrote, you do you get it to print and save all data in separate rows to a csv file that I can use in excel ?

Comment: simple 1 line of code - I updated it above. Just need to change the path and/or filename that you want it to save as

Comment: @chitown88 awesome do you have a messager, im working on a school project, its do friday, i would love to ask you for advice on this later tonight and tomorrow, thank you

Comment: I do have messenger. But away from the computer til tomorrow. I’ll be available 9-3pm (London time). Shoot me an email and we can try to figure it out. Jason.schvach@gmail.com